# How to go to implementation by vsvim + r#

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, vsvim

I want to use r# and vsvim to go to implementation in visual studio. Like command "gd", but maybe "gi".

Can i do it?

Comment: By the way, is there an advantage to using the R# `Resharper.Resharper_GotoImplementation` over the VS built-in `Edit.GoToImplementation`?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can.

Assuming that you already have a `vsvimrc` customization file, you just need to add:

`map gi :vsc Edit.GoToImplementation<CR>`

FYI my full `vsvimrc` is [here](https://github.com/jcouv/dotfiles/blob/master/vsvimrc#L147), with many other tricks, such as:

```
map gk :vsc Edit.PreviousMethod<CR>
map gj :vsc Edit.NextMethod<CR>
map gr :vsc Edit.FindAllReferences<CR>
map <Leader>k :vsc Window.PinTab<CR>
noremap + :vsc Edit.CommentSelection <return>
noremap - :vsc Edit.UncommentSelection <return>
```

Comment: this is awesome. It is so шикарно!

Comment: Where did you get the list of Edit commands? I can't seem to find them anywhere on the internet.

Comment: You can find the list of commands in the VS keyboard settings.
The information is also available in text format (but not up-to-date with latest VS): http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/visual-studio-2010-keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: I had no idea you can do this.... Thanks for opening my eyes

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can! And it's exactly what I am doing. This is the relevant line from my _vsvimrc file:

    `nnoremap gi :vsc Resharper.Resharper_GotoImplementation<CR>`

Here are some other mappings you might find useful when using VsVim and R# together:

    `nnoremap gi :vsc Resharper.Resharper_GotoImplementation<CR>
    nnoremap ge :vsc Resharper.Resharper_GotoNextErrorInSolution<CR>
    nnoremap gh :vsc Resharper.Resharper_GotoNextHighlight<CR>
    nnoremap gm :vsc Resharper.Resharper_GotoFileMember<CR>
    nnoremap gu :vsc Resharper.Resharper_UnitTest_RunSolution<CR>
    nnoremap gr :vsc Resharper.Resharper_Resharper_UnitTest_RunContext<CR>
    nnoremap g2 :vsc Resharper.Resharper_Resharper_UnitTest_DebugContext<CR>
    nnoremap gU :vsc Resharper.Resharper_ShowUnitTestSessions<CR><C-F4>`